# How can I stop my modal dialog from closing on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have this button in a bootstrap modal dialog:

```
<button id="btnSelectAll" style="float:left">Select All</button>
```

The click event looks like this, all it is supposed to do is mark a bunch of checkboxes as checked.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSelectAll', function ()
{
    var $modal = $('#MyPanel');
    $modal.find('#aCheckBox').prop('checked', true);

});
```

Here is the markup for the modal itself (with specifics removed as it's a bit long and basically just a bunch of checkboxes with a few buttons at the end):

```
   <asp:Panel class="modal" ID="MyPanel" runat="server">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="width:30%">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <asp:Label ID="Header" runat="server" Text="Header" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 20px;" />
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text="Stuff:" />
                            </td>
                           <tr>
                    </table>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

The click event code is being hit as I see it in the debugger, but the modal dialog always closes immediately when I click the button. I can't seem to find anything online to explain why, Googling just gives me a bunch of "how do I close a modal on button click" type questions. I want to know how to *not* close it.

Comment: Can you also provide the markup for your modal? Any relevant JS for it would be useful, too.

Comment: Did you try using e.preventDefault(); ?

Comment: Made a quick modal with a button and checkboxes in the modal body, click the button and it checks all the boxes. Doesn't close. http://jsfiddle.net/wmbs3znt/

Comment: So this is supposed to check a bunch of checkboxes? Please tell me you didn't give a bunch of page elements the same ID, because `$modal.find('#aCheckBox').prop('checked', true);` shouldn't be how you're finding several items to do something to them....

Comment: @MattD thanks, I had to use preventDefault not sure why since everything else about my code matches yours (now... I didn't think to just check all the checkboxes at once and had a very long list lol) so thanks for making my code cleaner :D

Comment: @MattD and no they don't have the same ID. I'm really new to this stuff, not really aware of the "correct" way to do things yet.

Comment: I'm glad I could help in some way, just boggles my mind as to why you'd need to use `.preventDefault();` for this. Unless your button has the `data-dismiss` attribute set to "modal", or you're explicitly hiding the modal as part of the button click's actions taken, it shouldn't do anything to close the modal....

Comment: @MattD yeah it's sort of bothering me as well, lol. I don't have data-dismiss set anywhere. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the fact that the modal is an ASP panel but not sure.

Comment: @eddie_cat Well, by using `#aCheckBox`, you're looking for a page element with an ID set to "aCheckBox". `#` is the symbol to find something by ID, `.` is the symbol to find something by class. Since you're trying to find multiple checkboxes, you wouldn't do it by ID since you can't have the same ID on more than one element in "legal" HTML. You should find your checkboxes by a shared class name, or use `input[type=checkbox]` to get them using a bit of DOM traversal.

Comment: @MattD my real code didn't have them all with the same ID, I just had a really long list of the same statement with different IDs haha. I am going to change them to use one of the other methods you mentioned.

Comment: @eddie_cat Ah, I honestly didn't notice that. Very well could be why you had to use `.preventDefault();`. Could try it with the standard modal markup, as you should be able to use `<asp:...` tags within it. I have a modal in my current project with an ASP.Net dropdown that I populate on page load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just try `e.preventDefault`. From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) we have this

> Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event
> will not be triggered.

So, if you change your code to the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSelectAll', function (event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var $modal = $('#MyPanel');
    $modal.find('#aCheckBox').prop('checked', true);
});
```

your problem will be solved.